If the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|$ less than $k$ then each term in this series is dominated by $k$
I study this theorem
Theorem
Let $1 < p < \infty,$ and let $X$ be a Banach space. We denote by $w_p(X)$ the set of all sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$ with the property that $(x^*(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l_p$ for all $x^* \in X^*.$ For each $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in w_p(X),$ we define $\|x\|_p^{weak} = \displaystyle\sup_{\|x^*\| \leq 1} \left (\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x^*(x_n)|^p \right)^{1/p}$ where "sup" denotes supremum. We will prove that $(w_p(X), \|.\|_p^{weak})$ is a Banach space.
proof
In the step where we prove that this norm is a complete one. Let therefore $x^{(k)} = \left (x_n^{(k)} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in w_p(X)$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to the norm $\|.\|_p^{weak}.$ For each $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m,q \geq n_\epsilon,$ $$\|x^{(m)} - x^{(q)}\|_p^\text{weak} = \displaystyle\sup_{\|x^*\| \leq 1} \left (\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\vert x^* \left( x_n^{(m)}- x_n^{(q)} \right) \right \vert^p \right)^{1/p} \leq \epsilon $$
i.e.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x^*(x_n^{(m)}) - x^*(x_n^{(q)})|^p \leq \epsilon^p \  \forall x^* \in B_{X^*}.$$
Each term in this series is dominated by $\epsilon^p,$ so for every $n$
$$\|x_n^{(m)} - x_n^{(q)}\| = \sup_{\|x^*\| \leq 1} |x^*(x_n^{(m)}) - x^*(x_n^{(q)})| \leq \epsilon \  \forall m,q \geq n_\epsilon.$$ And so on...
I want to prove something that seems quite trivial
but i want to know how to write the proof for this simple information
why "Each term in this series is dominated by $\epsilon^p$"?
Is in the general if we have series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i| \leq k$ then $|a_i| \leq k$
i.e. if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \leq k$ then $|a_i| \leq k$ for each $i$??

Well, of course, because if $|a_1|>k$, then $\sum |a_i| \ge |a_1| > k$...

The sequence $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|$ is monotonically increasing. Hence $S_i \le \lim_{n\to\infty}S_n \le k$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. If there were some $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_i| > k$, then observe that $S_i = S_{i-1} + |a_i| > k$, which contradicts monotonicity.
